# using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, expression

I am new to regular expressions. I am using java regular expressions to match the following cases:

```
 - DOC_BS [\bDOC_[A-Z]+] and it works fine
 - DOC_BS1
```

How can i match both of the above statements in single regular expression statement. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the text you want to match and what is the regular expression? Your question is hard to read.

Comment: @LutzHorn was asking for regex that would match both the above cases :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add \d* for zero or more digits.

Or change [A-Z] to [A-Z|\d] if digits can be on any place after underscore character.

Answer (score 1):

**This will solve ur problem**

```
[\bDOC_[A-Z]+[0-9] {0,1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you'r okay with finding all numbers and letters after "_" extend the letter qualifier with 0-9

[**\bDOC_[A-Z0-9]+**]

Comment: like i said: "if you'r okay with finding all numbers and letters after _" proper questions result in proper answers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather find the letters and numbers separately, use the following:

```
[\bDOC_[A-Z]+[\d]*]
```